# DurandalJS composition calling Knockout twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, durandal

I am using DurandalJS with Knockout to load a page with data. The data is loaded with an ajax call, so the data isn't available until the callback is executed.

What is happening is that when the data is finally loaded and I call `ko.applyBindings(model)`, it has already tried to bind the data once, and it throws an error stating the data cannot be bound twice. I'd like to prevent Durandal from doing this and allow me to manually apply the bindings.

Code:

```
define(['plugins/router', 'durandal/app', 'gcharts', 'jquery'], function (router, app, gcharts, $) {

    var projectStatsModel = function (data) {

        this.projectId = data.projectId;
        this.projectName = data.projectName;
        this.projectDescription = data.projectDescription;
        this.projectPlatform = data.projectPlatform;

        this.projectPointsLabel = "Total Points: " + data.projectNumPoints;
        this.projectStoriesLabel = "Total Stories: " + data.projectNumStories;
        this.projectCreatedDateLabel = "Created " + data.projectCreationDate;
        this.projectUpdateDateLabel = "Last Updated " + data.projectModifyDate;

        this.projectEpics = data.projectEpics;
        this.projectStories = data.projectStories;

        return this;
    }

    var ctor = function () {

        function drawPage(data) {
            var model = projectStatsModel(data);
            ko.applyBindings(model);
        }

        function loadData() {

            var projectId = router.activeInstruction().params[0];

            $.ajax({
                url: '/ClubhouseData/GetProjectDetails',
                data: {
                    'projectId': projectId
                },
                type: 'GET',
                cache: 'false',
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    drawPage(result);
                }
            });
        }

        ctor.prototype.activate = function () {
            loadData();
        }
    };


    return ctor;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As a safety precaution before I apply bindings I always check if the element is already bound on my application.

```
if (isBound("container"))
    ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById('container'));
// Bind
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("container"));
```

My isBound Method:

```
var isBound = function (id) {
    if (document.getElementById(id) != null)
        return !!ko.dataFor(document.getElementById(id));
    else
        return false;
};
```

This will prevent your error from occuring, as it will remove the binding before applying it if already bound.